# Неверная запись в файл

Tags: c

Есть достаточно большой двоичный файл (ок. 1мб), он передается по сети для записи в файл на компьютере-приемнике (под windows). Но вот при запуске просто из проводника часть файла (именно конец файла) теряется. При запуске из cmd все работает как надо.

фрагмент кода:

```
//s - сокет
int n;
int l = 1195520;
char b[l];
puts("Getting...");
n = recv(s, b, l, 0);
  if(n < 0) return 1;
puts("Got file");
n = send(s, "got the file!\n", 14, 0);
if(n < 0) return 1;
FILE * f;
f = fopen("file1", "wb");
fwrite(&b, sizeof(b), 1, f);
fclose(f);
close(s);
puts("Wrote");
```

Comment: recv не обязан прочитать все. Он обязан прочитать хотя бы один байт (и возвратит это количество в переменной n).. Если нужно больше - читайте ещё и ещё.

Comment: @KoVadim, а есть ли какое-либо ограничение по кол-ву прочитанных байт?

Comment: Не больше, чем есть в буфере.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно `man recv(2)` (важная часть выделена мной):

> If  no  messages  are  available  at the socket, the receive calls wait for a message to arrive, unless the socket is nonblocking ...  The receive calls normally return any data available, **up to the requested amount**, rather than waiting for receipt of the full amount requested.

Для удобства нужна функция, принимающая из сокета все данные до конца (раз нам известен точный размер). Что-нибудь вроде такого (код не проверялся):

```
int recv_all(int socket, void *data, size_t size)
{
    size_t received_total = 0;
    ssize_t received_now = 0;
    size_t bytes_left = size;

    while(1) {
        received_now = recv(socket, data + received_total, bytes_left, 0);
        if (received_now < 0) {
            // как-нибудь обработать ошибку
            break;
        }

        received_total += received_now;
        bytes_left -= received_now;
    }

    return received_total;
}
```

Использовать так:

```
size_t received;
int data_size = 1195520;
char buffer[data_size];

size_t received = recv_all(sock, buffer, data_size);
if (received < data_size) {
    return 1;
}

FILE *f = fopen("file1", "wb");
...
```

Comment: а разве с флагом 0 после прочтения данные из сокета не удаляются?

Comment: Немного подправил функцию: `if (bytes_left <= 0)` вместо  `if (received_now < 0)`